# Exclude source file line range from a single lintr (NOT all lintr)

Tags: r, lintr

To check the code quality of my package I am using the package [lintr](https://github.com/jimhester/lintr) using the command

```
lintr::lint_package()
```

and get one result that I want to ignore:

> functions should have cyclomatic complexity of less than 15

How can I ignore this single "false positive" lintr result of a single lintr (`cyclocomp_linter`)
for a file (line number range)?

**Edit 1:** Currently I am using this `.lintr` config file as a workaround (by disabling the lintr completely):

```
linters: with_defaults(
    cyclocomp_linter = NULL # instead of NULL I could use: cyclocomp_linter(16)
  )
```

Answer (score 3):

Although it doesn't solve your problem exactly, you can wrap that function with `# nolint start` then `# nolint end` to prevent any linter from flagging that function.

The syntax for preventing a specific linter from flagging a specific set of lines is currently under development - see https://github.com/jimhester/lintr/pull/660 . This will be present in the next major lintr release (3.0.0).

Comment: Thanks for tracking my question and linking the new feature in the next release, really good news :-)

Comment: `# nolint start: cyclocomp_linter` is now supported in the dev version (not yet on CRAN)